# How to disable single-click-selects-all in Safari 6 address bar

Tags: safari, osx-mountain-lion

In Safari 6, a single click into the URL bar does not place the text cursor (as it does EVERYWHERE else), but instead it selects the entire URL (eg. it behaves the same as a triple click).

Did anyone find a way to turn this special behaviour off? I have to edit URLs all the time, and this makes it incredibly annoying. Especially as there is no alternative way to edit URLs,  except to click, wait for the double click threshold to time out, and click again.

Not even a double click works as expected. A single, double and triple click all select the entire URL.